# How do I hide API Keys in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: git, asp.net-core, github, blazor-webassembly, c#-10.0

How can I hide my `API Keys` stored in `appsettings.json` as I initialize in `Git`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leandro thank you for the suggestion. I however figured out `secrets.json` is a safer place to host the secrets securely (though locally) and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Is this the article from Microsoft Learn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement config. files. You will have a web.config file in your project and in this one you put the following inside < configuration >:

```
<appSettings file="hiddenappsettings.config"></appSettings>
```

Then you create a hiddenappsettings.config file and you do the following:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="APIKey" value="YourApiKeyValue" />
</appSettings>
```

To acces you will need to use **Configuration Manager** to access to that key